# Jquery prev appending to many elements

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html

I have a listview that outputs as a table. Inside of each `<td>` I have a `<div>` which contains a `<hidden>` element.

When a sibling of that element is clicked I have it read the hidden value of the `hidden` element with `jquery.prev()`.

It does the first element fine,  but when I click on another element it appends the first element i click orginally. Right now i am testing so i have a `alert` call the variable for testing and I get two alerts with the value of the `hidden` element the first one i clicked and now the second. this var continues to build. how do I just have prev get that one value?

Here is my markup:

```
          <div id="HypeShareAlbum" style="padding: 0;margin:0">
              <input type="hidden" value="<%#Eval("ID") %>"/>
              <asp:HyperLink runat="server" Text="Share Album"></asp:HyperLink>
          </div>
```

And my corresponding client code:

```
 $('#HypeShareAlbum a').click(function () {
            //Create/clear variiable for albumID
            var albumvalue = '';
            //Set Variable for albumid
            albumvalue = $(this).prev().val();
            //Dialog Settings
            var dialogsettings = {
                width: 447,
                minheight: 100,
                height: 356,
                position: ["center"],
                close: function () {
                    $('#ClonedEmail').html('');
                }
            };
            //DIALOG FOR SHARING ALBUM STARTS HERE
            //Show Share Album Dialog
            $('#ShareDialog').dialog(dialogsettings);
            //When Focusing out of main email check if exist
            $('#addemail input[type=text]').focusout(function () {
                //Checks main email
            });
            //Click Event for Adding more Emails to dialog
            $('#AddMoreEmails').click(function () {
                //Append Email
                $('#addemail').clone().appendTo($('#ClonedEmail'));
                //Remove and bind back fousout event
                $('#ClonedEmail input[type=text]').unbind('focusout');
                $('#ClonedEmail input[type=text]').focusout(function () {
                    //Check email and let user no if email is found or not
                });
            });
            //Cancel Dialog
            $('#CancelEmailShare').click(function () {
                $("#ShareDialog").dialog("close");
            });
            //Send Email Ajax and Cancel Dialog
            $('#SendEmailShare').click(function () {
                alert(albumvalue);
            });
            //DIALOG FOR SHARING ALBUM ENDS HERE
        });
```

Comment: Please include the relevant HTML.  It's hard to follow with just words describing it.

Comment: I did, i included the div and the jquery. Did it not show up?

Comment: The HTML was not showing up and needed some editing help by someone else - it shows now.  What you have shown is only the HypeShareAlbum div.  It doesn't show us what you're trying to get to with `.prev()` which is where you say the problem is and it doesn't show the second element that you click on that has the problem.  Please show that.  My wild guess would be that you have duplicate IDs, but without seeing the rest of the relevant HTML, that's just a wild guess.  Also, we are more likely to provide accurate help if you give us the actual generated HTML from the browser not the ASP source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of adding this value to a alert, i added it to a textbox for testing and it worked fine. Not sure why on a alert it was coming up multiple times but, its now working ok.